# Azure Functions on VNET cannot communicate to on-premises resources

Tags: azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have an VNET in Azure that is connected via a S2S tunnel to our on-premises network. This VNET contains a VM that is able to traverse the Virtual Network Gateway and access our on-premise resources. Our on-premise resources are able to see the VM. We have added an App Service plan (EP1) and a function to this VNET. The Function app can communicate/ping the VM, however, it cannot ping our on-premise resources. I've been over the documentation repeatedly and based on everything we've been able to determine, we're configured correctly.

Is this just something that Azure is unable to do? Or has anyone had this type of setup work for them?

I'm contemplating abandoning the App Service plans and just running Kubernetes on the VM and calling it a day.

Comment: Is using a Hybrid connection any use for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#hybrid-connections and https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/13/azure-functions-azure-functions-using-hybrid-connections/

Comment: Does this issue be solved on your side?

Comment: We are not using a Hybrid Connections or Private Endpoints. We need access to all of our on-premise resources and really cannot afford the time to manage and maintain hundreds of private endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you may check the following aspects according to your current description.

- Use Azure Functions Premium plan or a dedicated plan(Require a Standard, Premium, PremiumV2, PremiumV3, or Elastic Premium pricing plan.)
- In native Windows apps, the tools ping, nslookup, and tracert won't work through the app console, you could use `tcpping.exe hostnameorPrivateIPaddress [optional: port]` to test for TCP connectivity to a host and port combination.
- Set the app setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` with the value `1` to make sure all of your outbound calls from your app into your VNet. If you are using Azure DNS private zones, you also need to set `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` with the value `168.63.129.16`.
- Use an empty(not other resources deployed inside the subnet) or dedicated subnet in your Azure VNet to integrate with the function app. To avoid any issues with subnet capacity, you should use a `/26` with 64 addresses.
- You're trying to reach a non-RFC 1918 address by using the regional VNet Integration feature.
- Is your on-premises gateway configured to route traffic back up to Azure?
- Is there an NSG blocking egress from your integration subnet?

Let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: We've confirmed all of this. I've spent a good deal of time with MS support and we've come to the conclusion that is has to do with the order in which we configured our VNET.

We created the VNET with the virtual machine and then connected our S2S Tunnel. It is believed (and we will be testing this later in the week) that if we tear down the S2S tunnel, and rebuild it AFTER the dedicated function subnet has been added to the VNET, that the connection process will properly configure routes. Since the subnet was added after the S2S, the routes didn't get properly created on our side.